# Print complex number

Tags: delphi, complex-numbers

Using embarcadero XE7 and System.VarCmplx - need to present a complex number as a string. Simple example where a complex number is created and the intent is to show it in the caption of the form. My problem is that I can not figure out how to get the complex number to a string - should be '1.23+4.56i'.

```
unit Unit57;
interface
uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, 
    System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
    System.VarCmplx,
    Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
    TForm57 = class(TForm)
      procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    end;

var
  Form57: TForm57;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm57.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
v : Variant;
begin
  v := VarComplexCreate( 1.23, 4.56 );
  // following does not work
  Caption := v.AsString;
end;
end.
```

Comment: FWIW this is a really inefficient way to work with complex numbers

Comment: Hi David - what do you suggest?

Comment: An enhanced record with operator overloading.

Comment: @David: already deleted that comment. In the Delphi Samples, subdirectory ComplexNumbers, there is actually a record implementation by Hallvard Vassbotn. Knowing Hallvard, it should be pretty optimized. <g>

Comment: @HenrikLyder: as I commented to David, there is actually a (as far as I can see) better implementation, using extended records, in the Samples subdirectory ComplexNumbers. Try that out. It does not require variants, and can more or less be used like any other value type, e.g. like a Double or Integer.

Comment: @Rudy Right off the bat the fact that the record is packed destroys any hope of good performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite simple, actually:

```
  v := VarComplexCreate(1.23, 4.56);
  Caption := v;
```

On my German Windows, this shows

```
1,23 + 4,56i
```

No need for `.AsString`.

If you want custom formatting, you can use the real and imaginary parts directly, and do something like:

```
var
  A, B: Extended;
  ...
  A := v.Real;
  B := v.Imaginary;
  Caption := Format('%.3f+%.3fi', [A, B], TFormatSettings.Invariant);
```

That shows:

```
1.230+4.560i
```

Note: There is a *public* property `AsString` in the implementation, but apparently only the *published* properties can be accessed from code. I *guess* it was made public because it is not needed by the user anyway.

---

*Note that your code doesn't compile. Although it looks as if you copied and pasted this from the Delphi editor, there is no proper `var` section in the procedure, so that can't compile. Please always use copy and paste.*

---

There is actually a (as far as I can see) *much better* implementation of complex numbers, by *Hallvard Vassbotn*, using extended records instead of variants. It comes with the Samples that are (usually) installed together with Delphi. Just look in the `<your samples dir>\Delphi\RTL\ComplexNumbers` directory. This uses extended records, so it can be used like a normal value type, i.e. like a Double or an Integer.

Comment: @HenrikLyder: if so, then you could accept the answer (click the grey checkmark near the score for the answer, to turn it green).